# Optimization Exception Remix Editor

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I am trying to compile my solidity code in remix editor. I keep getting this error "Optimization exception during compilation". I was using solidity version 0.5.2 till day before yesterday. Now, It is not letting me choose the version or higher version which is nightly build. [image]

Comment: Are you using the online version of remix?

Comment: yes. i am using the browser version of remix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exit, to clear the cache of the browser and restart. Compile without optimizer as first try and, if it is ok, switch on the optimizer.

I currently use 0.5.2 and I did not encounter problems.

I saw something similar using 0.4.24, but it was related to the browser.

(EDIT AFTER COMMENTS FOR REFERENCE OF READERS: it resulted to be exactly that: a browser related problem. Changing the browser solved, but clearing the cache resulted in the loss of the code, not backed-up. There is the suggestion to use the npm remix-ide complete with remixd in order to avoid those occasional loss.)

Comment: turned out to be a browser specific issue for me. I switched to Chrome and it worked fine. I am not sure why i still have the same issue with firefox

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Issue i am facing turns out to be a browser specific trouble. I was able to deploy my contract successfully from chrome. One mistake I did before backing up my code in Remix IDE in firefox is that I cleared cache and browser history without having a backup. So, I lost the smart contract code. Thankfully, I remembered most of it that I could rewrite the code.

Comment: Yes, the browser of the cache is used as temporary storage for remix files. May be you can have some advantages if you install remix-ide from npm and use remixd. In that a way your files shall be ever synced with the remix window.